# How do you loop through SQL query results? (and some further questions about SQL result manipulation.)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a fairly simple script to write: I have to total all of the international calling costs for my organization. I have two tables: the phonelog table, and the rates table.

The solution I've settled on is simple:

select the destination country code and the call duration from the phone log table

select from the rates table the cost per minute (using the destination country code that i just selected)

then multiply the duration and the cost per minute (CPM), for every international call, and add it to a variable named total, which is at the end displayed to the user.

Now, were I able to write this in whatever I wanted, I would be able to do this in about 30 mins. However, I've been told I have to write the great majority of it in SQL.

So I've googled a bit and settled on using a stored procedure, so:

How would I traverse the results of the first select query? If this were in ColdFusion or PHP, I would simply put the results in an array - but I haven't found a way to insert the results of one query into an array in SQL.

Second: is there a way to condense these steps?

for example:

```
total = 0
select destinationareacode, duration from phonelogs, where destination=international 
for each record, select CPM from rates, where areacode = (record.destinationareacode)
 total+=CPM*(duration/60)
```

And then the total gets displayed to the user.

Anyways...to clarify my questions:

How do I traverse through a set of query results? Is it possible to do another query while traversing those results, using the results themselves (areacode) as conditions in that query?

Sorry if all this seems convoluted, I'm not sure how else to phrase my questions.

Comment: Show your **schema**, **sample data**, **expected result**.

Comment: There is no need to traverse the rows, just sum the results. If you add the create statements for the tables then it would be easy to show you the sql to do that.

Comment: shiplu: I've no idea what my schema is. Sample data?

basically two tables: one contains two fields destinationareacode, and duration

the other contains two fields as well: areacode, and costperminute.

basically I just have to multiply the duration * the matching areacode



@kjtl, each areacode has its own international rate. if I were to use sum, I would have to have X sums, where X is the number of different area codes. Isn't it easier to just traverse the results, multiply then add to a total?

Comment: Cursors are how you loop a record set. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

Comment: Cursors are _not_ required for this task.

Comment: @Valkyrio, schema = table structure.  if you don't know what your schema is, how could you write a query at all?

Comment: Try 'describe tableName' for each table in your query to get the schema.

Comment: @nathangonzalez because I didn't set up this database. I've only been asked to write, in SQL, something that does what I described in my question. Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: I recommend reading Joe Celko's 'Thinking in Sets'. You're trying to solve a set based problem with a procedural approach. https://www.google.com.au/search?q=thinking+in+sets

Answer (score 2):

you probably want something like

```
select rates.areacode, sum(cpm*(duration/60))
from  phonelogs
    join rates on rates.areacode = phonelogs.destinationareacode
where phonelogs.destination = 'international'
group by rates.areacode
```

theoretically this will give you the total cost of all phone calls in the log by area code.  i obviously have no idea if it will work for you without any knowledge of the tables, etc, but this should give you an idea of where to go.  *in general*, if you're wanting to do a loop in sql, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Nice try without schema Nathan :-). I think he's looking for a grand total.

Comment: I am looking for a grand total, however Nathan's answer has set me on the right path. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You're clearly used to [imperative programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) languages (where one explicitly defines the machine's state and the flow of execution control from operation to operation), whereas SQL is much more [declarative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) (where one merely expresses computation logic).

It's a very different [paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm) that's well worth investing some time in studying, not least because it's incredibly useful (and somewhat ubiquitous) in the field of relational databases, but also because one can learn a great deal about programming generally from studying alternative paradigms.

In your case, what you want to do is select the sum of each call's duration (in minutes), multiplied by its cost per minute:

```
SELECT SUM(duration/60 * CPM)
```

You're obtaining this data from the `phonelogs` and `rates` tables, joined on area code:

```
FROM   phonelogs JOIN rates ON rates.areacode = phonelogs.destinationareacode
```

And that's it (except, perhaps, for qualifying columns with table identifiers if there's any ambiguity):

```
SELECT SUM(phonelogs.duration/60 * rates.CPM)
FROM   phonelogs JOIN rates ON rates.areacode = phonelogs.destinationareacode
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of this the wrong way. Thanks a lot for the explanation, this should help get to my solution.